# PHP how to add multiple strings to another string at certain positions

Tags: php

I have string in PHP in variable, like:

```
$datetime="20160105 1134";
```

I would like to call some simple function to add certain strings at certain positions. To get

```
$datetime="2016-01-05 11:34";
```

I know I can do it with substr() and such, but is there any simplest solution, which would simply tell PHP to put "-" at positions 4 and 6 and to put ":" at position 11? I wrote my own function for this, but I'm asking if this is somehow possible more easily eg. using regex or so.

```
// my function
function put($what,$pos,$txt)
{
   if (!is_array($pos)) $pos=[$pos]; rsort($pos);
   foreach($pos as $p) $txt=substr($txt,0,$p).$what.substr($txt,$p);
   return $txt;
}

$datetime=put("-",[4,6],put(":",11,$datetime));
// result: 2016-01-05 11:34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is using regex

```
$datetime="20160105 1134";
$datetime=preg_replace("{^(....)(..)(..)(...)}","\\1-\\2-\\3\\4:",$datetime);
```

similarly

```
$var="test string";
$var=preg_replace("^(....)(.)(......)","\\1-\\3",$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

is this simple enough?

```
$datetime="20160105 1134";
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($datetime));
echo $datetime;
```

Comment: This is very elegant! but only works for my particular case (dates). I would like to see more general solution for any string

Answer (score 0):

Try this [method](http://php.net/substr_replace)

```
$newstr = substr_replace($oldstr, $str_to_insert, $pos, 0);
```